# Stata overwrite all observations in cross section except last 20 non NA

Tags: panel, stata

I have a large strongly unbalanced panel in Stata, where each cross section only has a few observations, and the rest is NA (.).

I want to overwrite all non NA observations that are not the last 20 non NA observations, in each cross section. I'm not sure how to correctly specify the range, but you can see my thoughts below. There are gaps between the observations.

Thanks

*Edit

I removed the code as it created uncertainty. It was included to show what I had tried.

My cross section dimension identifier is xsection
My time dimension identifier is id01

*Edit

I have created an example below. The code needs to extract the last 3 non NA (.) values of each cross section in variable x, and enter these into a new variable z. Alternatively, all observations in x should be set to . except the last 3 (with allowed gaps). It does not matter if a new variable z is created, or the observations in x is replaced so that it looks like z.

```
id01    xsection      x             z
2005        1         20            .
2006        1         21            .
2007        1         22            . 
2008        1         23            23
2009        1         37            37
2010        1         38            38  
2011        1         .             .
2012        1         .             .
2005        2         24            .
2006        2         25            .
2007        2         21            .
2008        2         27            27
2009        2         33            33 
2010        2         .             .  
2011        2         37            37
2012        2         .             .
```

Comment: Very unclear for several reasons: 0. "last" in precisely what sense? 1. no reproducible example 2. mix of code and pseudocode 3. cryptic details (what is meant by `#variable = x`; you aren't counting variables, but presumably observations, but precisely how?) 4. what is a cross-section here?  Please show a worked example with realistic data showing what you have and what you want. Best not to guess at code if you are not fluent in Stata.

Comment: Now the example makes it clear. Thanks. See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that NA is the jargon of some other programs, but not native to Stata. Stata calls these "missing values".

If you just (1) segregate the observations with missing values, then immediately (2) identifying the last so many observations with non-missing values follows from sorting within the other observations, those with non-missing values.

```
. clear 

. input id01    xsection      x             z

          id01   xsection          x          z
  1. 2005        1         20            .
  2. 2006        1         21            .
  3. 2007        1         22            . 
  4. 2008        1         23            23
  5. 2009        1         37            37
  6. 2010        1         38            38  
  7. 2011        1         .             .
  8. 2012        1         .             .
  9. 2005        2         24            .
 10. 2006        2         25            .
 11. 2007        2         21            .
 12. 2008        2         27            27
 13. 2009        2         33            33 
 14. 2010        2         .             .  
 15. 2011        2         37            37
 16. 2012        2         .             .
 17. end 

. gen ismiss = missing(x) 

. bysort ismiss xsection (id01) : gen z_last = z if _N - _n < 3 
(10 missing values generated)

. sort id01 xsection 

. assert z_last == z
```

Here `z` was supplied as what was wanted and `z_last` is calculated and shown to be equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a bit clunky, but it should get the job done. If x is the variable that you want to replace values to missing,

```
by xsection: gen maxCount = _N
by xsection: gen counter = _n
gen dropVar = maxCount - counter
replace x = . if dropVar >= 20
```

I am fairly sure that the equal sign should be included, but this would be easy to check.

Comment: Various difficulties here. I an not clear that this is what the OP wants, but it can be reduced, I think, to one line `bysort xsection (id01) : replace x = . if (_N - _n) < 20` Not tested, but your inequality seems the wrong way round. No new variables need be created at all. I am inferring that `xsection` is an identifier and `id01` a time variable. Otherwise the OP's `xtset` is the wrong way round!

Comment: @Nick.  My interpretation was that the OP wants to set all but the last 20 obs in each group to missing: that is, obs 1,2,...,N-20 are set to missing so analysis would occur on the final 20 obs for each group. Using the _N notation directly in an if statement is pretty cool. I will have to add that to my coding. Q: What is the (id01) doing in your nice one line improvement?

Comment: The use of `in -20/l` (better as `in -20/L`)  in the OP's (pseudo)code was what drove my interpretation. I think we need to bounce this back.

Comment: @Nick Cox. That is great to know. It's similar to an assert command. Thank you for the follow up.